# Laravel routing and CSRF protection

Tags: php, laravel, csrf

If I have this line of code in my routes.php file:

```
Route::when('*', 'csrf', array('post', 'put', 'patch', 'delete'));
```

Do I still need to do this?

```
Route::group(array('before' => 'csrf'), function() {
    Route::post('/search', array(
        'as' => 'search-post',
        'uses' => 'SearchController@postSearch'
    ));
});
```

Or is it ok to just do this?

```
Route::post('/search', array(
    'as' => 'search-post',
    'uses' => 'SearchController@postSearch'
));
```

Comment: How can I check it it's working though? I'm not familiar with CSRF protection.

Comment: Remove the CSRF token from your form, submit it and check if you get an error. It SHOULD throw an Exception.

Comment: @rotaercz In your browser's dev tools, change the value of the `input type="hidden" name="_token"` field.

Comment: Or what @ceejayoz said

Comment: Man, you guys are awesome. I'll be right back.

Comment: Yup, it's working as it should even without Route::group(array('before' => 'csrf'), function() { }); Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Route::when` filters (internally called *pattern filters*) are called right before `before` filters. You're all good with just using your routes normally.

Here's the relevant source code:

```
public function callRouteBefore($route, $request)
{
    $response = $this->callPatternFilters($route, $request);

    return $response ?: $this->callAttachedBefores($route, $request);
}
```

As you can see first the pattern filters will be called. If they return any response it will be returned from here, otherwise the "normal" before filters will be called.

Comment: You answer a lot of my questions and I'd like to say thanks publicly. When I launch the site there's going to a be a shout out section. I'd like to thank you in there. Shall I add you as lukasgeiter or would you like me to put your name there?

Comment: You're very welcome :) Well "lukasgeiter" is actually my name. You can write it "Lukas Geiter" if you prefer ;)

Comment: Will do and I'll send you a link! :)

Answer (score 2):

Yes; you should be safe with just `Route::post('/search', [...]);`.